# Looping through a series of folders and pasting the file contents into an ultimate compilation document - VBA word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am very new to VBA and struggling to find examples of VBA code using word, not excel. I am writing a code that will cycle through a series of files sorted into different folders and copy the files to an ultimate compilation document. Any guidance would be beneficial! So far, I have a code to go through the bookmarks in the master documents and then a code to open the finder This is what I have so far (I added comments to the area I have errors with):

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    AskUserProjNum
    AskUserBA

    HostFolder = "Z:\" & sProjectNumbers & "\" & sBuildingAddress & "\"
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    Dim Docc
    
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        'Operate on each file
        'Copy file contents
        'paste under specific bookmark
        
        
    Next
    
End Sub

Sub AskUserProjNum()
sPrompt = "Please input project number"
sTitle = "Project Number"
sDefault = "1111"
sProjectNumber = InputBox(sPrompt, sTitle, sDefault)

End Sub
Sub AskUserBA()
sPrompt2 = "Please input Building Address"
sTitle2 = "Building Address"
sDefault2 = "Address"
sBuildingAddress = InputBox(sPrompt2, sTitle2, sDefault2)

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and hoping someone has any advice on how to solve this!

Comment: To find VBA information for Word, search on _"Word" VBA_ plus the rest of your terms. The double quotes make it mandatory that the results include that name. If you still get too much Excel info, add _-Excel_ to the search.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html. The code there goes through the selected folder. For the modifications that would be needed to loop through sub-folders as well, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/47785-post14.html

Comment: I modified your question changing "master document" to "ultimate compilation document" because of the chance of confusion with the faulty Word Master Document "Feature." http://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart